# Best ways, tips and examples to improve a code with Groovy and Java

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy, refactoring

I am using a BDD agil methodology to design and create a new system, but I am new at code refactoring, could you help me? What can I do to improve this code, and which tips do you follow every time you guys want to improve a code.

Thank you a lot.

Here you can find the Groovy code made to test some features:

```
package client

import com.resiflex.client.domain.Client

class DeleteSpec extends Base {
    def "delete client"() {
        given: "I have the code of client created"
        def clientCreatedResponse = clientService.createClient(clientName, clientColor, currentDescription)
        def code = null
        if (clientCreatedResponse.getObject() != null) {
            def clientCreated = (Client) clientCreatedResponse.getObject()
            ids.add(clientCreated)
            code = clientCreated.getCode()
        }
        when: "delete client"
        def result
        if (code == null) {result=clientService.deleteClientByCode(code ,tenants).getError().code} else if (tenants != "0"){
            result=clientService.deleteClientByCode(code ,tenants).getError().code
        }
        then: "client is deleted"
        expect == result
        where:
        clientName | clientColor | currentDescription      | tenants | expect
        "PCI"      | "#121273"   | "Positive Care Ireland" | "0"     | null
        "POCI"     | "#FF5FF5"   | "Positive Care"         | "1"     | 4022
        "POCIN"    | "#FF555F"   | "Positive Care"         | "0"     | null
        null       | null        | null                    | "0"     | 4021
    }

}
```

Here you can find the main Java class:

```
package com.resiflex.client.service;

import com.resiflex.client.domain.Client;
import com.resiflex.client.dto.ClientResponse;
import com.resiflex.client.utils.cleaner.StringCleaner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.resiflex.client.repository.ClientRepository;
import com.resiflex.client.utils.BusinessException;
import com.resiflex.client.utils.validators.ClientValidator;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ClientService {
    @Autowired
    ClientRepository clientRepository;
    ClientValidator validator = new ClientValidator();
    StringCleaner cleaner = new StringCleaner();

    public ClientService(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    public ClientResponse createClient(String name, String color, String description) {
        ClientResponse response = new ClientResponse();
        try {
            String cleanName = cleaner.removeWhiteSpace(name, (short) 4003, "name");
            String cleanColor = cleaner.removeWhiteSpace(color, (short) 4004, "color");
            if (validator.isValidName(cleanName) && validator.isValidColor(color)) {
                if (validator.isUniqueName(clientRepository.findByName(cleanName.toUpperCase())) &&
                        validator.isUniqueColor(clientRepository.findByColor(cleanColor))) {
                    Client client = new Client();
                    client.setName(cleanName.toUpperCase());
                    client.setColor(cleanColor);
                    client.setCode(client.generateCode(0, 0, getClientCodes()));
                    client.setDescription(description);
                    clientRepository.save(client);
                    response.setObject(client);
                }
            }
        } catch (BusinessException be) {
            response.setError(be);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setError(new BusinessException((short) 4007, "client_form"));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    public ClientResponse getAllClients(String status) throws BusinessException {
        ClientResponse response = new ClientResponse();
        try {
            response.setObject(clientRepository.findAllByStatus(status));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setError(new BusinessException((short) 4015, "client_list"));
        }
        return response;
    }

    private List<String> getClientCodes() {
        List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Client cli : clientRepository.findAll()) {
            codes.add(cli.getCode());
        }
        return codes;
    }

    @Transactional
    public ClientResponse updateClientDesc(String code, String desc){
        ClientResponse resp = new ClientResponse();
        Client client = clientRepository.findByCode(code);
        if (client==null){
            BusinessException businessException = new BusinessException((short) 4016, "client_form");
            resp.setError(businessException);
        }else{
            if (desc.length()<=30) {
                client.setDescription(desc);
                resp.setObject(clientRepository.save(client));
            }else{
                BusinessException businessException = new BusinessException((short) 4008, "description");
                resp.setError(businessException);
            }
        }
        return resp;
    }

    @Transactional
    public ClientResponse updateClientColor(String code, String color){
        ClientResponse resp = new ClientResponse();
        Client client = clientRepository.findByCode(code);
        if (client==null){
            BusinessException businessException = new BusinessException((short) 4016, "client_form");
            resp.setError(businessException);
        }else try {
            String cleanColor = cleaner.removeWhiteSpace(color, (short) 4004, "color");
            if (validator.isValidColor(color)) {
                if (validator.isUniqueColor(clientRepository.findByColor(cleanColor))) {
                    client.setColor(cleanColor);
                    clientRepository.save(client);
                    resp.setObject(client);
                }
            }
        } catch (BusinessException be) {
            resp.setError(be);
        }
        return resp;
    }

    public ClientResponse deleteClientByCode(String code, String tenants) {
        ClientResponse resp = new ClientResponse();
        Client client = clientRepository.findByCode(code);
        if (client==null){
            BusinessException businessException = new BusinessException((short) 4021, "user_blank");
            resp.setError(businessException);
        }else{
            if (tenants.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                clientRepository.delete(client);
                resp.setObject(null);
            }else{
                BusinessException businessException = new BusinessException((short) 4022, "delete");
                resp.setError(businessException);
            }

        }
        return resp;
    }

    public Client findByCode(String code) throws Exception {
        return clientRepository.findByCode(code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try asking this question here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ SO is not about doing peer review and giving suggestions related to refactoring etc.

Comment: *" .... which tips do you follow every time you guys want to improve a code."* - And this part of your question is too broad.  It may be more appropriate on a discussion board where opinion-based debates are welcome.

Comment: Stephenc C, I was asking for personal tips more than methodology tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of things to keep in mind:

- use truthy - e.g. you don't need to check if something is null. `if (clientCreatedResponse.getObject() != null) {` can be `if (clientCreatedResponse.getObject()) {` and `if (code == null)` can become `if (code)` etc.
- Don't worry about declaring something null. If it's uninstantiated it's definitely null.
- Don't inline conditionals. `if (code == null) {result=clientService.deleteClientByCode(code ,tenants).getError().code} else if (tenants != "0"){`
   is insane and unpleasant to read. You could refactor it into a ternary if you really wanted it inline. That being said, you're testing the result of a client call based on an input - I wouldn't recommend writing a test with conditional results from the client - you should restructure your test. feed the client an input, test the result. That being said..
- `def clientCreatedResponse = clientService.createClient(clientName, clientColor, currentDescription)` should be your `def result =` line. If a piece of data is going to affect the result, make that a part of your matrix. Your test should just consist of setup, the result (being the snippet you're calling) and the expectation. Feed everything that affects this into the data table and cut out all the rubbish aside from that